How configuration Framework Patrol-Flutter?
I'm try configuration framework Patrol-Flutter,but I'cant.
I'm use Patrol for testing automation with flutter in my projet poc.
I'm fallowing the official documetation https://patrol.leancode.co/ , but is very dificult..
Are you help me? please, thank you very much!
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
